# Maven: how to clean all modules from all profiles

Tags: maven, ant

I have a project with multiple plugins, each activated (or deactivated) by certain system property. As those plugins have differently versioned dependencies, I load each plugin in it's own classloader - each plugin has its own folder in project distribution, which built by Ant (within Maven) by looping over the plugins and copying the build plugins.

When I type mvn clean, I'd like the whole project to be cleaned, not just those project active by default. Is there some maven possibility to do that, or do I have to write Ant clean task? (or have a batch that would enumerate all the plugins).

Comment: Can you show an example of you pom cause that sounds a little bit weird. May be you have an example project somewhere online?

Comment: I have simplified the problem in a description - the problem is that in the Ant tasks I have things like "copy from foobar/target/foobar.jar to distribution/foobar/", and module foobar build is activated in profile. When I run one build with mvn install -Pfoobar, in further mvn clean install (no foobar) the foobar.jar is still there to be copied into distribution.